# How to wrap CKEditor contents in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I'm using **CKEditor 4**,

To support **RTL** languages (like **Persian**) I need to wrap it's contents in a `div` with `dir` attribute set to `rtl`:

```
<div dir="rtl">
    <!-- Content goes here -->
</div>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [editor#getData](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-getData) event to modify outputted content:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'yourInstanceHere', {
    on: {
        getData: function( evt ) {
            evt.data.dataValue = '<div dir="rtl">' + evt.data.dataValue + '</div>';
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: can we do this to specific elements only for example, wrapping tables only with div?